# What is the partial differential symbol (bent lowercase $d$) with an $x$ at the top?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, computational-science

From a government website on global warming:

$PT = LT / (1 - s)$, where the sensitivity coefficient $s = ðln(LT) / ðln(B)$ and $B =$ burden.

I have seen this before, yet there is never an explanation as to what it means.....

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with mathematics, but limitations of the website infrastructure. The character is Icelandic eth, which merely looks the most like $\partial$ while staying in Latin-1.

$\partial$ in HTML is U+2202, `&part;`.